# Scaling and rotating an image inside a border

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to know how this can happen when you hover over the image: http://stylemixthemes.com/demo/cinderellawp

I am aware of the transformation code which can scale and make the image to rotate, however, I can't think of a way to make the image rotate and scale only inside the border.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `overflow:hidden` on the images container element to make the overflow from the rotated/scaled image disappear.

Example:

```css
.image_container {
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  width:480px;
  height:270px;
}

.image_container img:hover {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(5deg) scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform:rotate(5deg) scale(1.05);
  transform:rotate(5deg) scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div class="image_container">
  <img src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-Bottles.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Just one more thing. On the link provided, the scale transition is much smoother, how I can achieve the same effect ?

Comment: Use a css transition. For example `transition:0.2s transform ease`. Add it with the selector `.image_container img`.